# can't call jquery dialog on result of find

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, find

All,

I am trying to make a JQuery dialog box appear when the user clicks an image.

Here's a stripped-down version of my HTML:

```
<div class="MyHelpButton" style="display: inline;">
    <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/img/MyHelpIcon.png"/>
    <div class="MyHelpText" title="MyTitle">
        here <i>is</i> <u>some</u> <b>text</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".MyHelpText").dialog({autoOpen:false});
    $(".MyHelpButton").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".MyHelpText").dialog("open"); // this doesn't work
        //$(".MyHelpText").dialog("open"); // this works
    });
});
```

As you can see, the dialog("open") function only works when I use the class selector directly and not when I use the find() function.  But since there will be potentially *loads* of MyHelpButtons on the page, I have to be able to find this particular MyHelpText (the one that is a child of the MyHelpButton that was clicked) - Hence my use of find().

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to work a little on your answer acceptance, your at 0%.  It's not opening though, because .find didn't return any items. Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/find/ and see what is wrong.

Comment: This works: `$($(this).selector + " .MyHelpText").dialog("open");`  http://jsfiddle.net/QGgyq/

Comment: That's done the trick.  Many thanks for your help

Comment: There is a green check box to the left of each answer to your questions. If it is correct and helped you, just click it! :) I'll move my comment to an answer if you would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This works:](http://jsfiddle.net/QGgyq)

```
$($(this).selector + " .MyHelpText").dialog("open");
```

A selector with the synatx $("{someselector} {anotherselector}") is prompts jQuery to perform a descendant search as documented here:

http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cL7nX/3, hope it will help you.

Comment: Recreating a ui dialog on the click handler each time is a recipe for a nasty memory leak.

Comment: What if you call $(this).remove() on the dialog's close button click. http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cL7nX/3

Comment: I double checked with Sieve, at least in IE, that solution leaks a copy of the dialog html objects each click.

Comment: I have a project that does something similar. I setup a single instance of the dialog with one internal div called content. Then each time I want to show the dialog I populate the content div, then show.

Comment: Actually, that's what I wound up doing in the end.  Much simpler.